# Can a css border be forced to cover a div's margins?

Tags: html, css

Anybody know any tricks how to make a border-top extend over a div's margin?

Comment: what about (padding) ..

Comment: Please post an example with code that explains exactly what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this ? [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hEtfG)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  margin-top:20px;
}
.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```